# How to databind a gridview to an ExpandoObject

Tags: c#, dynamic, expandoobject, expando

When I try to databind an ASP.NET `GridView` to an `IEnumerable<ExpandoObject>` using an `ObjectDataSource`, I get the following exception.

> System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): DataBinding: 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' does not contain a property with the name 'StoreID'.

Anyone know how I could databind to `ExpandoObjects`?

Comment: I know it can be done - [I've done it](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2008/11/dynamic-objects-part1.html) - unfortunately I lost some files from that exercise, though. If it is important I could probably reconstruct it, but the key here will be something like `ICustomTypeDescriptor` and/or `ITypedList`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The opensource framework [Impromptu-Interface](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/) can do this. It has a method for exposing dynamic object properties for reflection by passing in a dictionary of property names->types.

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> tProxiedObject = listOfExpandos.Select(x=>Impromptu.ActLikeProperties(x, x.ToDictionary(k=>k.Key,v=>typeof(object))));
```

Comment: This works. But it does not support two way binding. When i try to update, the object sent to the update method is empty.

Comment: @OrPaz: you could try ImpromptuInterface.MVVM https://www.nuget.org/packages/ImpromptuInterface.MVVM/4.0.13